# Why does a view I think I made public, still prompt me for login? - Rails3 + decl_auth

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, declarative-authorization

This is my `authorization_rules.rb`:

```
role :guest do
    has_permission_on [:paying_users], :to => [:index]
end
```

This is my `paying_users.rb` controller:

```
class PayingUsersController < ApplicationController
    filter_resource_access

    def index
        @users = User.all
    end

end
```

This is my `routes.rb`, the relevant parts anyway:

```
resources :paying_users
```

When I go to `myapp.com/paying_users` it still redirects to me login page, even though I want it to not do that.

How do I fix this?

Using declarative_authorization to handle authorization.

Answer (score 1):

All I had to do was add a `before_filter` before my `filter_resource_access` like so:

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!, :except => :index
```